# XML Choice without nesting

Tags: xml, xsd

What I'm trying to accomplish is the creation of an XML schema which describes an XML file which can take one of two forms.  There's a section of common elements between the two and then a small section which differs.  Something like:

```
<Dessert>
  <Identifier> Hot Fudge Sundae </Identifier>
  <SaleDate> 2013-06-03 </SaleDate>
  <Duration> 2 </Duration>
  <Size> SuperScooper </Size>
</Dessert>

<Dessert>
  <Identifier> Dutch Apple Pie </Identifier>
  <SaleDate> 2013-06-03 </SaleDate>
  <Duration> 1 </Duration>
  <AlaMode> 1 </AlaMode>
  <IceCreamFlavor> Vanilla </IceCreamFlavor>
</Dessert>
```

So for the ice cream desserts there's just a **Size** while for the pies there's an **AlaMode** indicator and an **IceCreamFlavor** specifier.

What I want to accomplish is to use the `xs:choice` specifier to indicate that the `Dessert` XML will either have one or the other (`Size` or `AlaMode` and `IceCreamFlavor`) so that I can validate them.

What I've tried to do is create two types and  do something like this:

and then do something like:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="Sundae" type="SundaeType" />
  <xs:element name="Pie" type="PieType" />
</xs:choice>
```

And but the resulting XML, of course, has a layout like so:

```
<Dessert>
  <Identifier> Hot Fudge Sundae </Identifier>
  <SaleDate> 2013-06-03 </SaleDate>
  <Duration> 2 </Duration>
  <Sundae>
    <Size> SuperScooper </Size>
  <Sundae>
</Dessert>
```

Which doesn't match the existing file structure.

I can simply make the union of all possible elements and do away with the `xs:choice` stuff but that really doesn't convey the expectations of the format (that it is, for instance, not valid for the sundae to have an `AlaMode` element).

Is there any way to accomplish this?  I suspect if I had just one field different I could accomplish this with the `xs:choice` (perhaps) and not have that additional level.  Or maybe I'm just missing something here.

And yes, I realize that the layout isn't the best but it is an existing format that I can really change at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind imposing an order on the elements in the source documents you can make this work using xs:sequence:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="Dessert">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Identifier" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="SaleDate" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="Duration" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="Size" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="AlaMode" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="IceCreamFlavor" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>

        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Dessert" type="Dessert"/>
</xs:schema>
```